# How to better format all worksheets in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I have the below code that will loop through all `worksheets` of the `workbook`and will format each sheet by deleting, change page orientation, page margins and be able to print each sheet on 1 paper.

The below it's working but it takes time as the `Call editingProperties`is quite long and takes time to go through it for all sheets.

Is there a better way to write the `editingProperties` sub?

```
 Dim ws As Worksheet

Public Sub editAllSheets()

' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+E
'
Dim myResult As VbMsgBoxResult

myResult = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to edit all sheets in this workbook?", vbQuestion + vbOKCancel + vbDefaultButton1, "Edit workbook")
If myResult = vbCancel Then Exit Sub

   On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

        For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.Activate
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Call editingProperties
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
            Next ws
        Sheets.Select
        MsgBox "Please note:" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "1. All the sheets are selected." & vbNewLine & "2. Proceed with print preview to view and print all reports." & vbNewLine & "3. To print preview or print only 1 report of this workbook you need to click on a different sheet to deselect all.", vbInformation, "Process Completed!"

    Exit Sub '<--- exit here if no error occured
ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "Sorry, an error occured." & vbCrLf & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error!"

End Sub

Private Sub editingProperties()

    Columns("A:E").Select
    Range("A4").Activate
    Selection.UnMerge
    Columns("B:C").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("D:D").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("E:G").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("H:J").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("K:K").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Range("A1:B2").Select
    Selection.Merge
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .PrintTitleRows = ""
        .PrintTitleColumns = ""
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = ""
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .LeftHeader = ""
        .CenterHeader = ""
        .RightHeader = ""
        .LeftFooter = ""
        .CenterFooter = ""
        .RightFooter = ""
        .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.7)
        .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.7)
        .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
        .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
        .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
        .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
        .PrintHeadings = False
        .PrintGridlines = False
        .PrintComments = xlPrintNoComments
        .PrintQuality = 600
        .CenterHorizontally = False
        .CenterVertically = False
        .Orientation = xlLandscape
        .Draft = False
        .PaperSize = xlPaperLetter
        .FirstPageNumber = xlAutomatic
        .Order = xlDownThenOver
        .BlackAndWhite = False
        .Zoom = 100
        .PrintErrors = xlPrintErrorsDisplayed
        .OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter = False
        .DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = False
        .ScaleWithDocHeaderFooter = True
        .AlignMarginsHeaderFooter = True
        .EvenPage.LeftHeader.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.CenterHeader.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.RightHeader.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.CenterFooter.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.LeftHeader.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.CenterHeader.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.RightHeader.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.CenterFooter.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .PrintTitleRows = ""
        .PrintTitleColumns = ""
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = ""
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .LeftHeader = ""
        .CenterHeader = ""
        .RightHeader = ""
        .LeftFooter = ""
        .CenterFooter = ""
        .RightFooter = ""
        .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
        .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
        .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
        .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
        .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
        .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
        .PrintHeadings = False
        .PrintGridlines = False
        .PrintComments = xlPrintNoComments
        .PrintQuality = 600
        .CenterHorizontally = False
        .CenterVertically = False
        .Orientation = xlLandscape
        .Draft = False
        .PaperSize = xlPaperLetter
        .FirstPageNumber = xlAutomatic
        .Order = xlDownThenOver
        .BlackAndWhite = False
        .Zoom = 100
        .PrintErrors = xlPrintErrorsDisplayed
        .OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter = False
        .DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = False
        .ScaleWithDocHeaderFooter = True
        .AlignMarginsHeaderFooter = True
        .EvenPage.LeftHeader.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.CenterHeader.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.RightHeader.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.CenterFooter.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.LeftHeader.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.CenterHeader.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.RightHeader.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.CenterFooter.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .PrintTitleRows = ""
        .PrintTitleColumns = ""
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = ""
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .LeftHeader = ""
        .CenterHeader = ""
        .RightHeader = ""
        .LeftFooter = ""
        .CenterFooter = ""
        .RightFooter = ""
        .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
        .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
        .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
        .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
        .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
        .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
        .PrintHeadings = False
        .PrintGridlines = False
        .PrintComments = xlPrintNoComments
        .PrintQuality = 600
        .CenterHorizontally = False
        .CenterVertically = False
        .Orientation = xlLandscape
        .Draft = False
        .PaperSize = xlPaperLetter
        .FirstPageNumber = xlAutomatic
        .Order = xlDownThenOver
        .BlackAndWhite = False
        .Zoom = False
        .FitToPagesWide = 1
        .FitToPagesTall = 1
        .PrintErrors = xlPrintErrorsDisplayed
        .OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter = False
        .DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = False
        .ScaleWithDocHeaderFooter = True
        .AlignMarginsHeaderFooter = True
        .EvenPage.LeftHeader.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.CenterHeader.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.RightHeader.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.CenterFooter.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.LeftHeader.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.CenterHeader.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.RightHeader.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.CenterFooter.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .PrintTitleRows = ""
        .PrintTitleColumns = ""
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = ""
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .LeftHeader = ""
        .CenterHeader = ""
        .RightHeader = ""
        .LeftFooter = ""
        .CenterFooter = ""
        .RightFooter = ""
        .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
        .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
        .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
        .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
        .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
        .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
        .PrintHeadings = False
        .PrintGridlines = False
        .PrintComments = xlPrintNoComments
        .PrintQuality = 600
        .CenterHorizontally = False
        .CenterVertically = False
        .Orientation = xlLandscape
        .Draft = False
        .PaperSize = xlPaperLetter
        .FirstPageNumber = xlAutomatic
        .Order = xlDownThenOver
        .BlackAndWhite = False
        .Zoom = False
        .FitToPagesWide = 1
        .FitToPagesTall = 1
        .PrintErrors = xlPrintErrorsDisplayed
        .OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter = False
        .DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = False
        .ScaleWithDocHeaderFooter = True
        .AlignMarginsHeaderFooter = True
        .EvenPage.LeftHeader.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.CenterHeader.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.RightHeader.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.CenterFooter.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.LeftHeader.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.CenterHeader.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.RightHeader.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.CenterFooter.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
         Cells.Select
         Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
         Range("A3").Select

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm flagging this question as off-topic because it should be migrated to CodeReview as stipulated here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266749/migration-of-code-questions-from-stack-overflow-to-code-review Reason: the code is working and the OP himself / herself asks merely for a "better way" (improvement) but not to overcome an error or implement something new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your code now correctly deletes the columns from right to left. I point out that .Columns("T:T") is the same as .Columns("T") which is the same as .Columns(20).

As an alternative to deleting columns successively you can unite them into a single range and then delete the range, like this.

```
Dim Rng As Range

With Ws
    Set Rng = Application.Union(.Columns("B:C"), _
                                .Columns("E:F"), _
                                .Columns("J:H"), _
                                .Columns("N:P"), _
                                .Columns("T"))
    Rng.Delete
End With
```

Be sure not to repeat the "With Ws .... End With. Repetition does not harm but it detracts from the code's readability.

Comment: Amazing thank you very much for your help I'm still in the learning process so the above code is new to me thank you for sharing your knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at the structure of my code below. I corrected some of the errors, made a few improvements and started you out on how to program your long list of properties. When you continue adding to the list make sure that you don't copy all the repetitions. It's enough to set a property once.

```
Public Sub EditAllSheets()
    ' 01 Apr 2017
    ' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+E

    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim myResult As VbMsgBoxResult

    If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to edit all sheets in this workbook?", _
                      vbQuestion Or vbYesNo Or vbDefaultButton1, _
                      "Edit workbook") <> vbYes Then Exit Sub

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each Ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        EditProperties Ws
    Next Ws

    Sheets.Select
    MsgBox "Please note:" & vbCr & vbCr & _
           "1. All the sheets are selected." & vbCr & _
           "2. Proceed with print preview to view and print all reports." & vbCr & _
           "3. To print preview or print only 1 report of this workbook" & vbCr & _
           "    you need to click on a different sheet to deselect all.", _
           vbInformation, "Process Completed!"

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub '<--- exit here if no error occured

ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "Sorry, an error occured." & vbCrLf & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error!"
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Private Sub EditProperties(Ws As Worksheet)
    ' 01 Apr 2017

    With Ws
        .Range(Columns(1), Columns(5)).UnMerge
        ' .Range(Columns("A"), Columns("E")).UnMerge      ' can also work
        .Range(Columns(2), Columns(11)).Delete shift:=xlToLeft
        .Range("A1:B2").Merge
        With .PageSetup
            .PrintTitleRows = ""
            .PrintTitleColumns = ""
            .PrintArea = ""
            .LeftHeader = ""
            .CenterHeader = ""
            .RightHeader = ""
            .LeftFooter = ""
            .CenterFooter = ""
            .RightFooter = ""
            .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.7)
            .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.7)
            .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
            .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
            .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
            .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
            .PrintHeadings = False
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but i've tried the above code and after the first sheet is done it's going to the second sheet and hits the errorhandler Method range of object _Worksheet failed.

Comment: Found the error i think because of the loop each sheet needs to be activated before edited. Please let me know your thoughts on it. Can i select all sheets and edit all of them at the same time?

Comment: No. You don't need - in fact, you don't want - to activate any sheet. The loop "takes" one sheet after another and calls it "Ws", and it is that variable "Ws" that you work on in the sub-routine - never the ActiveSheet. Your error handler will tell you the number and description of the error that occurred. You might want to disable the error handler to let VBA highlight the line of code that causes it. It might be in the sub-routine. Then you deal with the error. If you need help, let me know what error you get.

Comment: It's working perfectly thank you for your help and advice but the only code that is not working for me is  `.Range(Columns(1), Columns(5)).UnMerge
   .Range(Columns("A"), Columns("E")).UnMerge      ' can also work
        .Range(Columns(2), Columns(11)).Delete shift:=xlToLeft
        .Range("A1:B2").Merge` it's not deleting what i need there some bits that i need there.

Comment: I have the below code that works but its a bit long can't figure out a way to do it sorter look all over the internet for an answer but couldn't find so i started to delete column from right to the left just to make sure i'm not deleting something i don't want. `With Ws.Columns("T:T").Delete shift:=xlToLeft
    .Columns("N:P").Delete shift:=xlToLeft 
    .Columns("J:H").Delete shift:=xlToLeft
    .Columns("E:F").Delete shift:=xlToLeft
    .Columns("B:C").Delete shift:=xlToLeft`